# How to get the default.nix from a nix environment?

Tags: nix

First what I think I've understood:

```
nix-shell -p git
```

is the same as doing

```
nix-shell
```

if in the same directory there is a file default.nix with this content:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

stdenv.mkDerivation rec {   
       name = "name"; 
       env = buildEnv { name = name; paths = buildInputs; };   
       buildInputs = [git   ]; }
```

In the case I am right and I 've created an environment with the first method,
How can I get a default.nix file that I can reuse to recreate the same environment?

Comment: Just paste whatever you had after `nix-shell -p` into `buildInputs =[]`. Just like your example showed. You seem to have answered your own question there?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you :

```
 nix-shell -E 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; mkShell { buildInputs = [ git ]; }'
```

Is the same as:

```
nix-shell -p git
```